# Is it possible to have a tcblisting environment within an \ifthenelse?

Tags: errors, listings, conditionals, ifthenelse, tcblisting

I would like to choose which code to print according to a boolean flag.

If I use my `\ifthenelse` with plain text it works perfectly, but if I put a `tcblisting` environment instead of the plain text, it gives me this error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{marrone}{RGB}{215,151,66}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{0,58,121}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0, 108, 36}
\definecolor{arancione}{RGB}{236, 100, 0}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{236, 189, 0}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{publicedition}
\setboolean{publicedition}{true}
%\setboolean{publicedition}{false}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color{blue!40!red}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue!60!black}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!80!cyan}}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    escapechar=|, 
    alsoletter={\%},
    deletekeywords={SET, KEEP, LIBNAME, OBS, FIRSTOBS, DROP, IF, THEN,
        ELSE, RENAME, WHERE, PUT, DO, OR, AND, NOT, END, LENGTH,
        LABEL, OUTPUT},
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, \%macro, mend },
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs,  append, sort, sql,
        transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select, 
        format, informat, attrib,
        set, keep, libname, drop, if, then, else, rename, where, \%put, do,
        or, and, not, end, length,  label, output, lenght},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    otherkeywords={\&},
    morekeywords = [3]{\&},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    keywordstyle={[3]\stilecomandoa},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={%
        style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\relsize{0}\ttfamily
        }
}

\begin{document} 
\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}{%
this works
}{%
and this works
}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}{%
\begin{sas}
this doesn't work
\end{sas}
}{%
\begin{sas}
and this doesn't work
\end{sas}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work probably for the same reason it would not work with `verbatim` environment in place of `sas` as in your MWE: catcode changes attempted by start of environment are too late, because the whole thing served as argument to a macro (probably `\@firstoftwo` or  `\@secondoftwo`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a `lstlisting` environment in the argument to another command, because it's like `verbatim`.

Solution: `\newboolean{foo}` defines `\iffoo`. This won't work correctly if there are `\if...`, `\else` or `\fi` tokens in the skipped part.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{marrone}{RGB}{215,151,66}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{0,58,121}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0, 108, 36}
\definecolor{arancione}{RGB}{236, 100, 0}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{236, 189, 0}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{publicedition}
\setboolean{publicedition}{true}
%\setboolean{publicedition}{false}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color{blue!40!red}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue!60!black}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!80!cyan}}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    escapechar=|, 
    alsoletter={\%},
    deletekeywords={SET, KEEP, LIBNAME, OBS, FIRSTOBS, DROP, IF, THEN,
        ELSE, RENAME, WHERE, PUT, DO, OR, AND, NOT, END, LENGTH,
        LABEL, OUTPUT},
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, \%macro, mend },
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs,  append, sort, sql,
        transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select, 
        format, informat, attrib,
        set, keep, libname, drop, if, then, else, rename, where, \%put, do,
        or, and, not, end, length,  label, output, lenght},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    otherkeywords={\&},
    morekeywords = [3]{\&},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    keywordstyle={[3]\stilecomandoa},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={%
        style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\relsize{0}\ttfamily
        }
}

\begin{document} 

\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}{%
this works
}{%
and this works
}

\ifpublicedition
\begin{sas}
this works too
\end{sas}
\else
\begin{sas}
and also this works
\end{sas}
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

A different implementation using jfbu’s idea. In case the tokens `\THEN`, `\ELSE` or `\FI` appear in the language being dealt with, one can easily change them throughout to something else. The impact on the markup is minimal.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{marrone}{RGB}{215,151,66}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{0,58,121}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0, 108, 36}
\definecolor{arancione}{RGB}{236, 100, 0}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{236, 189, 0}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{publicedition}
\setboolean{publicedition}{true}
%\setboolean{publicedition}{false}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color{blue!40!red}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue!60!black}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!80!cyan}}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    escapechar=|, 
    alsoletter={\%},
    deletekeywords={SET, KEEP, LIBNAME, OBS, FIRSTOBS, DROP, IF, THEN,
        ELSE, RENAME, WHERE, PUT, DO, OR, AND, NOT, END, LENGTH,
        LABEL, OUTPUT},
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, \%macro, mend },
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs,  append, sort, sql,
        transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select, 
        format, informat, attrib,
        set, keep, libname, drop, if, then, else, rename, where, \%put, do,
        or, and, not, end, length,  label, output, lenght},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    otherkeywords={\&},
    morekeywords = [3]{\&},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    keywordstyle={[3]\stilecomandoa},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={%
        style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\relsize{0}\ttfamily
        }
}

\newcommand\IF[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \let\THEN\relax
    \let\ELSE\skipsecondpart
  \else
    \let\THEN\skipfirstpart
    \def\FI{\endgroup}%
  \fi
}
\let\ELSE\relax
\let\FI\endgroup
\long\def\skipsecondpart#1\FI{\endgroup}
\long\def\skipfirstpart#1\ELSE{}

\begin{document} 

\section{True}

\IF{publicedition}\THEN
\begin{sas}
this works too
\end{sas}
\ELSE
\begin{sas}
and also this works
\end{sas}
\FI

\section{False}

\setboolean{publicedition}{false}

\IF{publicedition}\THEN
\begin{sas}
this works too
\end{sas}
\ELSE
\begin{sas}
and also this works
\end{sas}
\FI

\end{document}
```

Comment: there will be a problem if e.g, first `sas` environement contains `\else` and `publicedition` toggle is false. Testing, I get another of those useful TeX error messages `Bad space factor (0).`, `I allow only values in the range 1..32767 here.`.

Comment: @jfbu `\else` is not so frequent in SAS code.

Comment: @jfbu I conferm, SAS has `else` and `%else` but not `\else`, so there's no problem :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Your question title does not mention SAS especially. People might use this as generic approach, inclusive of LaTeX code...

Comment: @jfbu You're right

Comment: I agree of course that in `99%` of cases, method is the most efficient.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{marrone}{RGB}{215,151,66}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{0,58,121}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0, 108, 36}
\definecolor{arancione}{RGB}{236, 100, 0}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{236, 189, 0}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{publicedition}
\setboolean{publicedition}{true}
%\setboolean{publicedition}{false}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color{blue!40!red}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue!60!black}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!80!cyan}}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    escapechar=|, 
    alsoletter={\%},
    deletekeywords={SET, KEEP, LIBNAME, OBS, FIRSTOBS, DROP, IF, THEN,
        ELSE, RENAME, WHERE, PUT, DO, OR, AND, NOT, END, LENGTH,
        LABEL, OUTPUT},
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, \%macro, mend },
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs,  append, sort, sql,
        transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select, 
        format, informat, attrib,
        set, keep, libname, drop, if, then, else, rename, where, \%put, do,
        or, and, not, end, length,  label, output, lenght},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    otherkeywords={\&},
    morekeywords = [3]{\&},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    keywordstyle={[3]\stilecomandoa},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={%
        style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\relsize{0}\ttfamily
        }
}

\begin{document} 
\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}{%
this works
}{%
and this works
}

\let\ENDOFGOBBLE\empty
\let\ENDOFGABBLE\empty
\long\def\GOBBLETOEND#1\ENDOFGOBBLE{}
\long\def\GABBLETOEND#1\ENDOFGABBLE{}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}
   {}{\GABBLETOEND}
\begin{sas}
this does work
\end{sas}
\GOBBLETOEND
\ENDOFGABBLE
\begin{sas}
and this does work too
\end{sas}
\ENDOFGOBBLE

\end{document}
```

[image]

and with boolean being `false`:

[image]

Comment: possible with one less macro (at least) but symmetry is fun.

Comment: Also this one is a good solution, thank you!

Comment: @egreg's one is better in that case: I did not even check what the test was doing. In more complicated situation, you may need something like this one (or first use `\ifthenelse` (do you really need it?) to set up some TeX boolean).

Comment: no wait! I said @egreg's solution was better, but this is wrong. See [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394695/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tcblisting-environment-within-an-ifthenelse/394701#comment981443_394705).

Comment: Are you telling me egreg was _wrong_? LOL

Comment: I must go to my fitness class, so must delay my reply ;-)

Comment: This has the same problem as the question: absorbing a `lstlisting` environment as an argument to a command disallows category code changes.

Comment: @egreg Not sure what you are referring to, I am not absorbing anything as argument to a command. I have not checked at all what happens in the OP's preamble though. But have a second look at my code in document body.

Comment: @jfbu Oh, I see now: you only absorb the skipped upon part.

Comment: @egreg ok, now I can go to my fitness class, all things cleared up `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

tcolorbox has a `void` key which throws away a box. You could use it along with a style to exclude some boxes:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{listings}


\newtcblisting{sas}[1][]{%
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
     #1   
}

\newif\ifsaspub

\tcbset{saspub/.style={\ifsaspub\else void\fi},sasdraft/.style={\ifsaspub void\fi}}

\begin{document}
x%
\begin{sas}[sasdraft]
draft \section{}
\end{sas}
y%
\begin{sas}[saspub]
pup \section{}
\end{sas}
z

\saspubtrue

x%
\begin{sas}[sasdraft]
draft
\end{sas}
y%
\begin{sas}[saspub]
pup
\end{sas}
z

\saspubfalse

x%
\begin{sas}[sasdraft]
draft
\end{sas}
y%
\begin{sas}[saspub]
pup
\end{sas}
z

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be an acceptable workaround.  Place both conditions in temporary boxes before the `\ifthenelse` test and then use the right box as a result of the test.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{marrone}{RGB}{215,151,66}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{0,58,121}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0, 108, 36}
\definecolor{arancione}{RGB}{236, 100, 0}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{236, 189, 0}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{publicedition}
\setboolean{publicedition}{true}
\setboolean{publicedition}{false}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color{blue!40!red}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue!60!black}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!80!cyan}}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    escapechar=|, 
    alsoletter={\%},
    deletekeywords={SET, KEEP, LIBNAME, OBS, FIRSTOBS, DROP, IF, THEN,
        ELSE, RENAME, WHERE, PUT, DO, OR, AND, NOT, END, LENGTH,
        LABEL, OUTPUT},
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, \%macro, mend },
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs,  append, sort, sql,
        transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select, 
        format, informat, attrib,
        set, keep, libname, drop, if, then, else, rename, where, \%put, do,
        or, and, not, end, length,  label, output, lenght},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    otherkeywords={\&},
    morekeywords = [3]{\&},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    keywordstyle={[3]\stilecomandoa},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={%
        style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\relsize{0}\ttfamily
        }
}

\begin{document} 
\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}{%
this works
}{%
and this works
}

\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{sas}
this doesn't work
\end{sas}
}
\setbox2=\hbox{%
\begin{sas}
and this doesn't work
\end{sas}
}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{publicedition}}{\copy0}{\copy2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good enough, I wait a bit before accepting as usual, but I think it's a good workaround, thank you!

Comment: This solution will make pagebreaks impossible. But possibly in this context they already are.

Comment: @jfbu They already are in my actual document, no problem!

Comment: @CarLaTeX all clear then...